# Recommendations for Soap Webservice Testing Apps

Tags: testing, soap, wsdl

I was looking for some recommendations for testing SOAP webservices. I want to be able to create requests from WSDL, see those requests, and inspect responses. I would also like it to work with WS* compliant services (such as when using WCF wsHttpBinding).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

I use SoapUI (http://www.soapui.org/) for all of my SOAP testing. It's a different client, so it doesn't really help if the client is making a bad request. In that case, I just use the normal debugger or Firebug to inspect the request/response.